# Conditional Order By In Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

For example I have this stored procedure

```
Create Procedure sampleProcedure
AS
BEGIN 
Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable
END
```

Now in my application how I will do this: For example a user checked the checkBox1 then the query above will be `ORDER BY EmpID` else if the checkBox2 is checked then the query will be `ORDER BY Name`. Do I have to create two procedures?

```
Create Procedure sampleProcedure1
AS
BEGIN 
Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By EmpID
END
Create Procedure sampleProcedure2
AS
BEGIN 
Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By Name
END
```

If checkbox1 is checked then sampleProcedure1 would be execute, else if checkbox2 is checked then sampleProcedure2 would be execute ?

Comment: small correction- you are creating a stored procedure, not executing it here.

Comment: you can pass a parameter to the stored proc to achieve the same.

Comment: no. the stored procedure is already created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce a parameter for the procedure to dictate the sort order:

```
Create Procedure sampleProcedure1
  @orderByEmpId bit
AS
BEGIN 
  if (@orderByEmpId = 1)
    Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By EmpID
  else
    Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By Name
END
```

You can further refine this to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sampleProcedure1
  @orderByEmpId Bit
AS BEGIN 
  SELECT
    EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber
  FROM EmpTable
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @orderByEmpId = 1 THEN EmpID ELSE Name END
END
```

Comment: How I will pass the parameter? `myCmd.Parameters.Addwithvalue("@orderByEmpId", "1")`?

Comment: `myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderByEmpId", 1)` should work, without the quotes. You want it to be interpreted as a number and not a string. If that doesn't work you might have to tell ADO .NET to treat the parameter as a bit rather than an integer. It's been a while since I've worked with the raw ADO .NET providers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ordering your collection in your application based on your checkbox selection. 
E.g.

```
if (checkbox1.Checked)
    employees = employees.OrderBy(x => x.EmpID).ToList();
else
    employees = employees.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

But if you need to do this SQL side for whatever reason, I would suggest a parameterized stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure sampleProcedure1 
(
    @OrderByEmpID BIT = 1
)
AS
BEGIN 
    IF (@OrderByEmpID = 1)
        Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By EmpID
    ELSE
        Select EmpID, Name, Address, PhoneNumber From EmpTable Order By Name
END
```

Comment: This is the most logical method, since it is the most efficient. If the user selects another sort order, you will not have to re-run the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only two sort values then you can go with any of the solutions mentioned already. If there are many sort parameters then you can consider dynamics SQL for this.

Here is a quick and dirty example that needs some more work…

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SortExamle
(
    @SortParam nvarchar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ICE_Users ORDER BY ' + @SortParam
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```